# I have a system call that somehow is causing malformed header from script Bad header

Tags: perl, cgi, system

I have a Perl CGI program. *myperlcgi.pl*

Within this program I have the following:

```
my $retval = system('extprogram')
```

*extprogram* has a print statement within.

The output from extprogram is being included within *myperlcgi.pl*

I tried adding

```
> output.txt 2>&1
```

to system call but did not change anything.

How do I prevent output form extprogram being used in *myperlcgi.pl*.

Surprised that stdout from system call is being used in *myperlcgi.pl*

Comment: qq and qx seemed to work better. Still surprised.

Comment: `>output.txt 2>&1` does indeed work (which you proved by saying `qx` works).  `qq` doesn't execute anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `system` command just doesn’t give you complete control over capturing STDOUT and STDERR of the executed command.

Use backticks or `open` to execute the command instead. That will capture the STDOUT of the command’s execution. If the command also outputs to STDERR, then you can append `2>&1` to redirect STDERR to STDOUT for capture in backticks, like so:

```
my $output = `$command 2>&1`;
```

If you really need the native return status of the executed command, you can get that information using `$?` or `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`. See `perldoc perlvar` for details.

Another option is to use the `IPC::Open3` Perl library, but I find that method to be overkill for most situations.